# Errors with Microsoft.Web.Mvc after upgrading to MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have upgraded an MVC site to MVC version 4.0, .NET Framewrok version 4.5.  After doing this I have been getting runtime errors from my Views:

Method Microsoft.Web.Mvc.LinkExtensions.ActionLink: type argument 'ContactCentre.Controllers.LogOnController' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TController'.

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
Url.Action<LogOnController>(c => c.LogOff())
```

Constraint TController is a check that the type is of type Controller.  My controller LogOnController does inherit from Controller, so that constraint is met.

I think the problem is with my version of library Microsoft.Web.Mvc.  This is Runtime Version v4.0.30319, Version 3.0.0.0.  I think this means it is targeting MVC version 3.

Is there a MVC version 4 compatable version of Microsoft.Web.Mvc?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?  Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

The Mvc4Futures NuGet package, published by Microsoft, has been available since 30 November 2012. It contains Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll version 4.0.0.0.

You can install it as follows:

- Open the Package Manager Console
- Select your web application from the Default Project menu
- Run the following command: `install-package mvc4futures`

Answer (score 3):

I added an assemblyBinding redirect in my config file and this fixed the issue.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```